# Unable to require 'memcached' in Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, memcached

I have installed Memcached and tried some simple examples, which worked fine. Now I am trying to create a server and use Memcached functionalities.

I have started with the most simple example.rb file:

```
require 'memcached'
  puts 'Hello'
```

However, when I try to load the file into I get the following error.

> /Users/matiii79/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/memcached-
>   1.8.0/lib/rlibmemcached.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000440 ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005)
>   [x86_64-darwin14]
>
> -- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------    See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
>        * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
>        * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
>        * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
>        * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports    for more details.
>
> -- Control frame information ----------------------------------------------- c:0009 p:-17567916705026 s:0039 e:000038 TOP    [FINISH] c:0008 p:---- s:0037
>   e:000036 CFUNC  :require c:0007 p:0113 s:0033 e:000032 METHOD
>   /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54 c:0006 p:0017 s:0023 e:000022 TOP
>   /Users/matiii79/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/memcached-1.8.0/lib/memcached.rb:19
>   [FINISH] c:0005 p:---- s:0021 e:000020 CFUNC  :require c:0004 p:0083
>   s:0017 e:000016 RESCUE
>   /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128 c:0003 p:0388 s:0014 e:000013 METHOD
>   /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39 c:0002 p:0007 s:0004 E:000820 EVAL   example.rb:1 [FINISH] c:0001
>   p:0000 s:0002 E:000f40 TOP    [FINISH]
>
> -- Ruby level backtrace information ---------------------------------------- example.rb:1:in `<main>' /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in`require'
>   /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in
>   `rescue in require'
>   /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in`
>   require'
>   /Users/matiii79/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/memcached-1.8.0/lib/memcached.rb:19:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
>   /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
>
> -- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------  rax: 0x0000000000000030 rbx: 0x0000000106766f59 rcx: 0x0000000000000000 
>   rdx: 0xfffffffffffffff0 rdi: 0x0000000000000030 rsi:
>   0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x00007fff598f6900 rsp: 0x00007fff598f6900 
>   r8: 0x0000000000000017   r9: 0x00000000f0000000 r10:
>   0x0000000000000a58 r11: 0x00007fff93182d10  r12: 0x00007fff78694070
>   r13: 0x00007fd2cb500000 r14: 0x0000000000000004  r15:
>   0x00007fff598f69e0 rip: 0x00000001067cbbe6 rfl: 0x0000000000010246
>
> -- C level backtrace information ------------------------------------------- 0   libruby.2.2.0.dylib                 0x00000001064a6ccb rb_vm_bugreport + 155 1   libruby.2.2.0.dylib
>   0x000000010634b0e0 rb_bug_context + 480 2   libruby.2.2.0.dylib
>   0x00000001064232a3 sigsegv + 83 3   libsystem_platform.dylib
>   0x00007fff93181f1a _sigtramp + 26 4   libruby.2.2.0.dylib
>   0x00000001067cbbe6 ruby_xmalloc + 17 5   ???
>   0x00007fff598f6920 0x0 + 140734695958816
>
> -- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------
>
> - Loaded script: example.rb
> - Loaded features:
>
>   0 enumerator.so
>     1 rational.so
>     2 complex.so
>     3 /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14/enc/encdb.bundle
>     4 /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
>     5 /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/unicode_normalize.rb
>     6 /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14/rbconfig.rb
>     7 thread.rb
>     8 /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14/thread.bundle
>     9 /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
>     10
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
>     11
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
>     12
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/errors.rb
>     13
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/version.rb
>     14
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
>     15
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/platform.rb
>     16
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
>     17
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
>     18
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
>     19
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb
>     20
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
>     21
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
>     22 /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb
>     23
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
>     24
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb
>     25
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
>     26
>     /Users/matiii79/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
>
> [NOTE] You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or
>   extension libraries. Bug reports are welcome. Don't forget to include
>   the above Crash Report log file. For details:
>   http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
>
> Abort trap: 6

Any ideas what is going on? Of course, if I remove the first line of the example.rb file, it loads fine.

Comment: The memcached gem documentation says: 'You need Ruby 1.8.7 or Ruby 1.9.2. Other versions may work, but are not guaranteed.' So it might be a compatibility problem.

Comment: I have ruby 2.2.0p0, how do I install Ruby 1.9.2?  I have tried with RVM and this is what I get: RVM does not know how to build working ruby-1.9.2-p330 on OSX 10.10,. Thanks!

Comment: If you can, I would recommend using the [Dalli memcached client](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) instead. It supports Ruby 1.9.3+

Comment: I will try it @Jesper. I am new on this: should I be able to perform every Memcached functionality with the Dalli cliente? Thanks!

Comment: @Matias Dalli is a fully featured memcached client which has pretty much supplanted all the other memcached clients for ruby out there. It should have all the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jesper suggested, I solved the issue using [Dalli memcached client](https://github.com/mperham/dalli).